# Why my input data length is 0 when there is one symbol?

Tags: javascript

when I type input my debugger shows `e.target.value` as 0 length, when I have already 1 symbol typed. what it can be? thanks in advance

```
handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      description: e.target.value,
    });
    if (this.state.description.length > 1) {
      const regex = /(^[a-zA-Z1-9]+[a-zA-Z1-9. ]+)$/;
      const match = regex.test(e.target.value);
      if (match !== false) {
         this.setState({
            validInput: true,
          });
      } else {
        this.setState({
          validInput: false,
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: How is the function called?

Comment: You mean `e.target.value.length` is returning 0 even when you type 1 or more letters?

Comment: handleChange. so what?

Comment: @Zuckerberg yes

Comment: Do you mean because `this.state.description.length` is always coming 0 or you have checked for `e.target.value.length` actually?

Comment: @Zuckerberg not always. i type 'a', but inside method it shows that `description` has 0 length. than i type one symbol more to a, for example, b (so we have 'ab'), and i shows `description.length` is 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `setState` happens in an asynchronous way, we need to check for validation of `description` in the `setState` callback like:

```
handleChange(e) {
   this.setState({description: e.target.value}, function() {
      this.validateDescription();
   });
},
validateDescription() {
   // This should return same length as you type
   console.log(this.state.description.length)

   if (this.state.description.length > 1) {
      const regex = /(^[a-zA-Z1-9]+[a-zA-Z1-9. ]+)$/;
      const match = regex.test(e.target.value);
      if (match !== false) {
         this.setState({validInput: true});
      } else {
         this.setState({validInput: false});
      }
   }
},
```